# Php echo table tag without space

Tags: php, html

In my case I want to echo echo image in table `td` tag and show on table.

I'm trying to use this code

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $row['rate']; $i++) 
        echo '<td><img src="/images/pjdict/star.png" width="20" height="20"></td>';
```

but the images have space because it echoes `td` tag every time how can I update this?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: i want to echo duplicate image in one td tag

Comment: @NonBrazilian you want all images from the loop in one td?

Comment: but in my code image have space because i echo td every time

Comment: @NonBrazilian just put the <td> tags outside of the loop. See Phiter Fernades answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want all the images from the loop to appear inside one single `td`, you must wrap the loop within the `td`.

```
echo '<td>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $row['rate']; $i++) 
    echo '<img src="/images/pjdict/star.png" width="20" height="20">';
}
echo '</td>;
```

If you want all images to be in the same row you must add a `inline-block` style.

```
echo '<td style="display: inline-block">';
```

Comment: Sem problemas, cara! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<td>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $row['rate']; $i++) {
            echo '<img src="/images/pjdict/star.png" width="20" height="20">';
        }
echo '</td>';
```